# Nano Server container with Jenkins and Chocolatey

Tags: docker, jenkins, chocolatey, nano-server, server-core

I need to have **Jenkins** and **Java** on a **Windows container** and I am investigating whether to use `Windows Server Core` or `Windows Nano Server`.

So that the assembly of the container is fast and the movement of DEV to PRO is agile. I see better Nano Server because it occupies 300MB instead of Server Core that occupies about 5 GB.

The problem comes when I want to install something in `Nano Server`. I tried to install `Chocolatey` but it is only compatible with the Server Core version, which makes me think that it is not advisable to use Nano Server for this functionality.

Is it advisable to use Nano Server to have Jenkins and Java or is it intended for another use?

Comment: Ignoring Chocolatey for a second, does Jenkins or Java even install and run correctly with Nano?

Answer (score 0):

The first reason (possibly among quite a few) why you should use `Windows Server Core` is that `Nano Server` does not support MSI installer files, which makes installing Jenkins more difficult.

Comment: Awesome Windows world about wizards.